# Operation finished with HTTP status code 409 (fail)

Tags: java, android, http, file-upload, image-uploading

Hello There I am working on [Next Cloud](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/9/developer_manual/android_library/examples.html) Api, and I am trying to upload an Image from my device as:

```
    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showFileChooser();
        }
    });

    private void showFileChooser() {
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
       intent.setType("*/*");
       intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

       try {
          startActivityForResult(
          Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),FILE_SELECT_CODE);
       } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
          // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
          Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    }
```

and the on activity result is as:

```
     @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    // Get the Uri of the selected file
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    // Get the path
                    String path = getPath(MainActivity.this, uri);
                    File fi = new File(path);

                    //set the image to image view
                    iv.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(fi));

                    Date lastModDate = new Date(fi.lastModified());
                    startUpload(fi, "/testfolder", getMimeType2(Uri.fromFile(fi)),lastModDate.toString());
                    Log.e(TAG, "file " + fi.toString() + " remote path " + mServerUri + " mime " + getMimeType2(Uri.fromFile(fi))+" date "+lastModDate.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "eee " + e.toString());
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public static String getPath(Context context, Uri uri) throws URISyntaxException {
    if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        String[] projection = {"_data"};
        Cursor cursor = null;

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_data");
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Eat it
        }
    } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}
```

---

Though I just created a new folder using the [api documentation](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/9/developer_manual/android_library/examples.html) and it works well good and created a folder! Although every this is working in good condition like reading a file from Next Cloud too!

The problem is with the image upload from the device! I am getting the following error while I am trying to upload:

```
  Operation finished with HTTP status code 409 (fail)
```

I currently have no idea what I have been doing wrong, can somebody please give some idea about what is being done wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Error 409 means that there is a confict with the resource on the server.
You should check the response from the server to understand how to resolve the confict.
More info: https://httpstatuses.com/409